# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [951, 2025]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

There are tons of samples from this error in which the problem is related with dimensions of the array or how a dataframe is read. However, I'm using just a python list for both X and Y.

I'm trying to split my code in train and test with train_test_split.

My code is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSuQ.png)

And this teh error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OM5m.png)

Please Help me for the solution

How to solve this error code for spliting my code in train and test with train_test_split?

Comment: you should add the code and error as text to your questions instead of attaching images.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into that error because your X and Y don't have the same length (which is what train_test_split requires)

```
X.shape[0] != Y.shape[0]
951 != 2025
```

Solution:
Try to convert X and Y to the same length.

Comment: I try to convert X and Y to the same length, but it's not changed.  Here is code # Concatenating all features to the 'X' variable.
X = np.concatenate((f_mfccs), axis=1)

# Preparing 'Y' as a 2D shaped variable.
Y = np.asarray(emotions).astype('int8')
Y = np.expand_dims(Y, axis=1)

X.shape[0] != Y.shape[0]
951 != 2025